# Algorithm for differentiating two different sets of points?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I was given two sets of points: let's call them group I and group II. They both are plotted, on a plane. How do I differentiate group I from group II, when each group contains thousands of points and only the computer knows which are which?

After finding a way to differentiate between the two groups of points, I will be given a list of points from group I and group II, but I don't know which point is in which group.

Comment: unclear what you're asking. try being more specific and concrete.

Comment: have you looked into clustering algorithms?

Comment: I have, but I don't really know how to program them.

Comment: Are the points in different (more or less separated) regions of the plane? If yes, could you roughly describe how these regions llook like? Maybe show an image.

Comment: Is the problem related to motion tracking or some other computer vision problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is unclear whether this approach yields a solution that works well in practice, a possible solution would be as follows.

Compute the bounding boxes of both point sets and move the bounding boxes to match; afterwards, model a [bipartite matchig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) problem by making Group I the left partition and Group II the right partition. The edge weight between the nodes is the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance). If a matching of minimum weight has weight zero, Group I and Group II are equal (as points could be matched); if the weight is larger than zero, Group I and Group II are different.The bipartite matching problem can be solved in polynomial time using the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).